# Using (Linux) iptables to drop duplicates?

Tags: linux, iptables, vmware, duplicate

Is there an easy way to use "iptables" rules to drop duplicate packets on Linux?

If not, I'll have to spend more time figuring out *why* the problem is happening.  In short, it has to do with a setup involving proxy ARP and routing between interfaces.

Regards,
Albert.

Comment: Please add more info about your setup and where do you see this problem.

Comment: There are 2 physical computers involved, a DELL Precision laptop and a Lenovo ThinkPad [TP].  The TP has a QEMU MacOS VM [MVM] and a VMware Windows 10 VM [WVM].  The WVM is bridged to the rest of the network.  The MVM is on a tun/tap device, and configured statically.  The rest are configured through DHCP.  All are on the same class-C subnet, but there is a /32 route to the MVM (tap0).  The TP host does IP forwarding and proxy ARP (between the MVM tap and the TP host's wifi).  When the MVM or DELL (but not TP host) pings (eg.) the WVM, there is a "storm" of duplicate packets from the WVM.

Comment: The placement of the "eg." in my comment above was unfortunate.  I did not mean "eg. the WVM" but "eg. ping".  The problem is most obvious with pings, but it happens with other sorts of IP traffic as well.